# C Programming Reading Chars from the Command Line

Tags: c

Let's say I type in $./file ABCDEFG into the command line and I want to store chose as individual chars in an array in my file.  Based on my research it should look something like this but it is not giving me any output.  The nextChar is calling a different function and can be ignored here.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    char findThisString[argc];
    while(i < argc){
        findThisString[i] = argv[i];
        i++;
        printf("%c \n", findThisString[i]);
    }

    while(c != EOF){
        nextChar();
    }
}
```

Comment: In `while(c != EOF) { nextChar(); }` what is `c` and what is `nextChar`?

Comment: Did you mean `char *findThisString[argc];` note the star. Also `%c` should be `%s`.

Comment: That is irrelevant right now.  At this point I just need to be able to read the input from the command line.  But right now c is a global int set = to 0 and nextChar is an empty function

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you delayed incrementing `i` until you were finished using that value. This is why most people use `for` loops for this kind of thing.

Comment: Even when I changed those two things I get nothing.  It compiles fine, but no output when I run it.

Comment: ... Although it is not at all clear to me why you feel you need to copy `argv` into a different array. `argv` is not going anywhere; it will still be there the next time you need ii.

Comment: The code as written will give you a slew of warnings -- *ALWAYS* use `-Wall` (or the equivalent for your compiler) and *pay attention* to the warnings.

Comment: So right now I can get it to print out ABCDE with the following code but I wanted a new line for each of them.  Each time it is run there is supposed to be a newline.

Comment: Well... now you got this far - printing the argument instead of nothing - take a break and look again at what you want to do: examine every character of the argument. BTW please check the number of arguments `argc` is sufficient.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing when I said findThisString[i] = argv[i]

Comment: `findThisString[j] = argv[i][j]` ... or as commented, just pick each character out of `argv[i]` instead of copying it first. It's still unclear what you doing with `findThisString`, justing copying what you already have to make the same thing, (but without any string terminator).

Comment: `int j = 0; while(argv[1][j] != '\0') { printf("%c\n", argv[1][j]); j++; }`

Comment: Thank you, this solved all of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

**first:** `char findThisString[argc];` . don't do staff like that. when you declare an array the compiler will need to know the size of the array to find and save place for the array. use pointers, `malloc` and `free`. this an undefined behavior that only allowed in C99.

**second:** `findThisString[i] = argv[i];` . you declared one of them as an array of strings (char*) and another as an array of chars (char).

**third:** did you declared `nextChar` somewhere?? use `getchar` instead.

**forth:** you write `int i=0; while(...){...; i++; }`. this is not an error but when you are writing this loop like this it is better to write 
`for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)`.

Comment: `char findThisString[argc];` is a *variable length array* (VLA), although still incorrect

Comment: that is dengerous for the compiler...  and will cost an error in any C that is not C99.

Comment: The compiler is never dangerous. If the VLA is implemented, it will work, otherwise compiler error.